# TypeError: 'filter' object is not iterable when using lambda function with yield

Tags: python, lambda, yield

I'm trying to use a lambda function with yield inside a generator function to filter a sequence of numbers and return only the even ones. However, I'm getting a TypeError when I try to **yield** from the result of the filter function. Here is my current code:

```
def generate_even_numbers(n):
    even_numbers = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(n))
    yield from even_numbers

for num in generate_even_numbers(10):
    print(num)
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
TypeError: 'filter' object is not iterable
```

I've tried converting the filter object to a list using the list function, but that didn't fix the issue. Can someone explain what is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the explanation for this is, but you should be able to just write `return even_numbers`.

Comment: what version of python are you running? I am able to run this without error on 3.9.13